# Filter files for autoformatting in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting, intellij-plugin, eclipse-formatter

I'm using IntelliJ 2016.2 and have imported our project eclipse formatting settings, set up with Eclipse Formatting. Is it possible to create an ignore filter that IntelliJ will use to decide which files should be auto formatted when saving? I'd like save actions to be disabled for *.py files.

Comment: Did you mean reformat on save, or reformat on checkin to VCS?

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ does not format files on save, a third-party plugin does that, check its config.

Comment: Perhaps, but he wrote "formatted when saving", not commiting :]

Comment: I wasn't clear - we're using the Eclipse Formatting plugin with IntelilJ which seems to very aggressively running autoformat on my .py files. What I have to do is just disable the plugin when I'm going to be modifying any python - ideally I'd like to have intellij / Eclipse plugin ignore the python scripts

Comment: Eclipse Formatting plugin does not autoformat, and it does not even format python, save actions plugin does.